# glfwSwapBuffers throws _com_error

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

I am using glfw 3.3.2 with the example program in the documentation:

```cpp
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GLEW/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

/* uncomment to attempt to draw a triangle
static unsigned int compile_shader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source) {

    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    // error handling
    int res;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &res);
    if (res == GL_FALSE) {
        // shader did not compile sucessfully
        int len;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
        char* msg = (char*) _malloca(len * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, len, &len, msg);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << 
            (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment")
            << " shader" << std::endl;
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static int create_shader(const std::string& vertex_shader, const std::string& fragment_shader) {

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint vs = compile_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex_shader);
    GLuint fs = compile_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragment_shader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}
*/

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();

        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

/* uncomment to attempt to draw a triangle
 if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "glew init error" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    // define vertex buffer
    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f
    };
    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 6, positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // enable the 0th (first) vertex attribute array
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // 0 means first attribute, 2 means how many vertex to represent the attribute (x and y)
    // sizeof(float) * 2 is the bytes needed to skip to get to the next attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

    // core means no depracated function
    // 330 is the version
    // location = 0 should match the first arg of gl vertex attribute pointer call
    std::string vertex_shader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";

    std::string fragment_shader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "  color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    unsigned int shader = create_shader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader);
    glUseProgram(shader);
*/

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

// uncomment the following to attempt to draw a triangle
//  glDeleteProgram(shader);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I got some weird  `Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error`:

```
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\University_of_Manchester\Projects\OpenGL\opengl_project\x64\Debug\opengl_project.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\umpdc.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DXCore.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
The thread 0x4b10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dinput8.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\XInput1_4.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\InputHost.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\nvdlistx.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\nvdlistx.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\nvoglv64.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. 
The thread 0x4bc0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4bc8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4bc4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvspcap64.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winsta.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\nvdlistx.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\nvdlistx.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\nvldumdx.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptnet.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\nvwgf2umx.dll'. 
The thread 0x25fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting64.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaci.inf_amd64_bf1cc4a1e8a34392\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting64.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvapi64.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_1d9a63fa126c4a34\igd10iumd64.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntasn1.dll'. 
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_1d9a63fa126c4a34\igc64.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
[...] more same exceptions here
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFE2AA839 in opengl_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000023B52FBAE0.
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_1d9a63fa126c4a34\igc64.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntasn1.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_1d9a63fa126c4a34\igd10iumd64.dll'
The thread 0x295c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2960 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2ae4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x48a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3f98 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\XInput1_4.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll'
'opengl_project.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dinput8.dll'
The thread 0x4bb0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4bcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4bb4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4bb8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4bd0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4ba4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4be0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2b40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4bac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4ba8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[19144] opengl_project.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

May I know why this happens and how to fix it?

When I remove the line `glfwSwapBuffers(window);` it gives no error.

#### update

I added a line in the `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))` loop to change the clear color bit: `glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);` before `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` But the color of the screen does not change.

I find that the first error message is generated from the first iteration at `glfwPollEvents();`. The second iteration did not generate any error message and from the third iteration onwards, the line `glfwSwapBuffers(window);` will generate the same error message every time it is called.

#### update 2

The debugger says that it comes from `d3d11.dll CDevice::OpenSharedResource()`.

Comment: Could it be a graphics driver issue? Did you try to update it to see if this has any effect? (I googled `igc64dll` because I was curious whether I could find out what graphics H/W you try on. I ended up e.g. here: [What is igc64.dll?](https://www.freefixer.com/library/file/igc64.dll-213109/).) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Hi I have just updated my drivers and it did not work, thanks for the reply

Comment: I also updated the log to show to full dll log in case it is relevant

Comment: I did [google "glfw windows intel graphics"](https://www.google.com/search?q=glfw+windows+intel+graphics) and found some interesting hits which might be of interest. (I'm a bit suspicious about OpenGL on Intel Graphics H/W although this might just be my personal feeling.)

Comment: Does the rendering work?

Comment: @user253751 Hi, yes it shows a frame with the correct title and white background, the exception message continuously popping up from the console. And if I add some line to draw a triangle in the frame, it does not show.

Comment: @Scheff Hi, I followed your link and had a look at the various results and tried some of their solutions but did not work out as well. Thanks

Comment: Notice it says the exception was thrown. It doesn't say the exception was uncaught and the program didn't crash. Perhaps this exception is normal for your graphics driver.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, but when I tried to render a triangle on the frame it did not work :/

Comment: Maybe you made some other mistake when drawing your triangle? However, have you tried using the debugger to break on this exception, and see which code (especially which DLL) it is coming from?

Comment: There are lots of mistakes you can make when you are trying to draw your first triangle, which will make the triangle not be drawn. I always test it by changing the clear colour. If you set the clear colour to red and the screen is red, then you change it to blue and the screen is blue, then OpenGL is working.

Comment: @derhass Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty sure it is from the glfw3.lib, the line generates the message is described in the update

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for the reply, I tried to set the color to red but it did not work:/

Comment: "'m pretty sure it is from the `glfw3.lib`" That is totally unclear, because that library calls into lots of other DLLs, `glfwPollEvents()` into `user32.dll`. Since GLFW is open source, one can also easily debug into it if one is suspecting it as the culprit. Btw, there might also be some software installed in your system which hooks into various parts, even the official Intel OpenGL ICD installs some windows message hooks, so it might get called at this point.

Comment: A nice tool to debug such situations on windows is [Rohitab API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor).

Comment: @derhass Thank you, I will have a try when I am free

Comment: @derhass Hi I went to use that tool but I couldnt get much information out of it, it seems like not properly capturing the glfw lib calls. But I did see some errors on some of the calls to graphics lib, I will try to have a look at them another day

Comment: Since the issue seems to be related to event polling, I thought it would be useful to trace all the windows events fucntions.

Comment: Tracing into glfw won't work when statically linked, of course. But since the source for GLFW is availablke, it is also utterly useless to trace it, you can simple use a debugger and get moche more information out of that.

Comment: @derhass Hi thanks for the suggestion. I tried to break on the error and it says it comes from the `d3d11.dll` and referring to: `CDevice::OpenSharedResource() error`, any idea?